# Increase accelerometer sampling rate in smartwatch by modifying device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, accelerometer

Normal accelerometer sampling rate available through API is 100 Hz, but I wanted a higher sampling rate. I found a research paper, in which the linux kernel is modified to get 4000 hz sampling rate. This [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXEfv.png) to an image gives an idea of the implementation.
As i have limited experience with writing/modifying kernel drivers, can someone provide any  help/guidance/resources?

Comment: I would suggest to find which accelerometer your smartwatch uses. Then search for the driver documentation or code in the linux source distribution for your smartwatch. Also, look into the accelerometer's vendor datasheet. If there is a way to change frequency it will be documented.

Comment: THANKS, BTW i am using the same smartwatch as used in the paper ( lg g w100)